# How to grab an element from the document in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What should be written inside the brackets instead of **XXX** so that the value in the input field is cleared?

```js
function App() {
    const searchInputElement = document.querySelector(**XXX**);
    searchInputElement.value = '';
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input id="birth" value="it-school"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I tried to add `onfocus="this.value=''"`  but it didn't work. I do not need to add a clear button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use the [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) hook to access elements. And if you want to clear the input on render without user interaction, use the [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) hook to make sure you are accessing it after it's fully rendered.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect }  from "react";

function App() {
  const searchInputElement = useRef();

  // Use the below effect to acces the element after it's mounted on the page.
  useEffect(() => {
    searchInputElement.current.value = "";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input id="birth" value="it-school" ref={searchInputElement} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And if you want to clear it on focus, you can do it like so:

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const searchInputElement = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="birth"
        value="it-school"
        onFocus={() => {
          searchInputElement.current.value = "";
        }}
        ref={searchInputElement}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```